# Set permissions on a compressed file in python

Tags: python, zip

I have a file `test.txt` that is inside a zip archive `test.zip`.  The permissions on `test.txt` are out of my control when it's compressed, but now I want them to be group-writeable.  I am extracting the file with Python, and don't want to escape out to the shell.

**EDIT:**
Here's what I've got so far:

```
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
zi = zipfile.ZipInfo('test.txt')
zi.external_attr = 0777 << 16L
z.writestr(zi, 'FOO')
z.close()

z = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'r')
for name in z.namelist():
    newFile = open(name, "wb")
    newFile.write(z.read(name))

    newFile.close()
z.close()
```

This works perfectly on OS X using 2.5.1, but it doesn't work on my home box (Debian, Python 2.4 & 2.5) or on RHEL 5 with Python 2.4.  On anything but OS X it doesn't error, but doesn't change the permissions either.  Any ideas why?  Also, how does `writestr()` work?  I know I'm using it incorrectly here.

Is there a way to do this without `os.chmod` (the user extracting the file doesn't have permissions to use `os.chmod` after it's extracted)?  I have full write access to the zip file.

More info:

```
> ls -l test.zip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 myuser mygroup 2008-11-11 13:24 test.zip
> unzip test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  inflating: test.txt 
> ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 2008-11-11 13:34 test.txt
```

The user extracting is not `myuser`, but is in `mygroup`.

Comment: The other thing you could do is elaborate on your problems under linux, as someone here may be able to help, but you haven't given anything to go on.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Linux is behaving fine, although python is behaving differently on OS X.

Comment: Well, you said "it works on OS X, not on Debian".  If you said why it doesn't work, maybe posted some code or error messages, someone might be able to help.  Just a thought.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  Brain not working properly today.

Comment: The user can unzip, but can't `os.chmod`? sounds strange.

Comment: Yeah they can write to the directory, but the file inside the zip archive is not group writeable.  It is a strange situation.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem to you, so here is the code spinet from my stuff, this I believe should help here.

```
# extract all of the zip
for file in zf.filelist:
    name = file.filename
    perm = ((file.external_attr >> 16L) & 0777)
    if name.endswith('/'):
        outfile = os.path.join(dir, name)
        os.mkdir(outfile, perm)
    else:
        outfile = os.path.join(dir, name)
        fh = os.open(outfile, os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY , perm)
        os.write(fh, zf.read(name))
        os.close(fh)
    print "Extracting: " + outfile
```

You might do something similar, but insert your own logic to calculate your perm value. I should note that I'm using Python 2.5 here, I'm aware of a few incompatibilities with some versions of Python's zipfile support.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, unzip sets the permissions to those stored, under unix.  Also, the shell umask is not used.  Your best bet is to make sure the perms are set before you zip the file.

Since you can't do that, you will have to try and do what you were trying to do (and get it to work under Debian.)

There have been a number of issues with Pythons zipfile library, including setting the mode of writestr to that of the file being written on some systems, or setting the zip systm to windows instead of unix.  So your inconsistent results may mean that nothing has changed.

So you may be completely out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

@Petriborg's answer is still relevant, but to work with Python 3, here is a version with the necessary fixes:

```
import os
import zipfile

zip_file = "/path/to/archive.zip"
out_dir = "/path/to/output"

os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, "r") as zf:
    for file in zf.filelist:
        name = file.filename
        perm = ((file.external_attr >> 16) & 0o777)
        print("Extracting: " + name)
        if name.endswith("/"):
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(out_dir, name), perm)
        else:
            outfile = os.path.join(out_dir, name)
            fh = os.open(outfile, os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY, perm)
            os.write(fh, zf.read(name))
            os.close(fh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract to stdout (unzip -p) and redirect to a file?  If there's more than one file in the zip, you could list the zip contents, and then extract one at a time.

```
for n in `unzip -l test.zip | awk 'NR > 3 && NF == 4 { print $4 }'`; do unzip -p test.zip $n > $n; done
```

(yeah, I know you tagged this 'python' :-) )