# Preserve file attributes in ZipFile

Tags: python, file, zip, python-zipfile

I'm looking for a way to preserve the file attributes (eg. read-only) of a file that gets written to a `zipfile.ZipFile` instance.

The files I add to the zip archive gets their file attributes reset, eg. the read-only flag is gone when inspecting the archive with zip applications and after unzip.

My current environment is Windows and I'm having problems with the [ZipInfo.external_attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zipf) method.

Surely there must be an standard way of preserving file attributes when writing to `ZipFile`?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain "I'm having problems". Otherwise, we can't help.

Comment: The original question is valid. That was just a side note on the solutions here on stackoverflow diddnt work, since I'm not implementing for unix.
Bad explanation though, point taken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem I had was the heavily undocumented zipfile.ZipInfo.external_attr. All examples I found of this object refeered to the *nix file permission style.

My implementation will run on windows.

So I went about some "reverse engineering". Heh.

The magic number for windows read-only ZipInfo.external_attr is 33.

As in:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(targetFile, 'w')
(path, filename) = os.path.split(sourceFile)
bytes = file(sourceFile, 'rb')
info = zipfile.ZipInfo(filename)
info.external_attr = 33
z.writestr(info, bytes.read())
bytes.close()
z.close()
```

If you need to find the correct value for another type of attribute create the zipfile as you want it with some windows zip app and run this on it:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(sourceFile, 'r')
info = z.getinfo('fileToTest.ext')
print ("create_system", info.create_system)
print ("external_attr", info.external_attr)
print ("internal_attr", info.internal_attr)
```

Cheers!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zipf/6297838#6297838 . You are right about the undocumented external_attr field.

Comment: I got in to same problem while using "minizip" in windows to presereve all file attributes. I used the following code : DWORD attribs = GetFileAttributesW(szOut); 
  zi.external_fa = attribs;