# Maintain file and folder permissions inside archives

Tags: linux, macos, zip

I am packaging and distributing a program I made for Windows,Linux and Mac. I plan to put the files and folders in zip archives.

If I set the correct folder and file permissions and then compress into zip and redistribute them, will those permissions be maintained when the user extracts them in Linux or Mac systems ? Or do they have to set the permissions themselves ?

Comment: There's no way to store permissions in ZIP file in cross-platform way.

Comment: Is there any other type of archive like tar,rar etc. that can store permissions ?

Comment: Since permissions are not portable, it's hard to understand how you plan to set them by just unpacking the same archive on multiple platforms. Installer (script or application) would be more useful for your goal.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp That is not strictly correct.  I have explained how this might be achieved using the InfoZip utilities in my answer to another question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185364/how-to-assign-execute-permission-to-a-sh-file-in-windows-to-be-executed-in-linu

Comment: @itsbruce infozip is a border case, not a generic solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`zip` does not store file permissions in the archive.

`tar` archives will preserve file permissions on Linux and OS X.  I have no idea what happens on Windows.  If you can test things out on Windows and it works, this is probably your best bet.  It probably depends on what tool people use to unpack the archives.

Another option would be to create an installer, although there are few non-commercial options for creating cross-platform installers.  Wikipedia has [a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software#Cross-platform).

Comment: Not entirely true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185364/how-to-assign-execute-permission-to-a-sh-file-in-windows-to-be-executed-in-linu

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zip/434689#434689

Comment: Zip can store Unix file permissions  by using the "external attributes" field inside the ZIP header. If it is uncompressed with the right tool on a unix system, the files will keep the permissions. If it is upacked on windows, the files will lose the permissions. I am wondering how this answer could have been selected as the right one and got 10+ points.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 20.04, the default behaviour of _Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP_ is to store and restore the execution permission.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/the-zip-formats-external-file-attribute has a very good writeup down to the bit-flags how the RWX masks per owner/group/other work in a ZIP file.

Answer (score 3):

An installer is your best option here.
Lets me explain a bit better why.

Windows has these permissions:

```
Modify
Read & Execute
Read
Write
```

Which are assigned to Groups or Usernames,

Unix based systems have:

```
Read
Write 
Execute
```

Which can be assigned to owner, group and others.

Has you can see, its difficult to map permissions from one system to another, since the filesystems handle permissions differently.

However some zip utilities like Info-Zip supports Unix based filesystem features, such as user and group IDs, file permissions, and support for symbolic links.  It also support NTFS filesystem permissions, and will make an attempt to translate from NTFS permissions to Unix permissions or vice-versa when extracting files. This can result in potentially unintended combinations, e.g. .exe files being created on NTFS volumes with executable permission denied.*

If you are planning on distributing your program, an installer is indeed your best solution.

*From wikipedia: [Zip (file format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))