# Preserving permissions while copying from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux

I gave execute permissions to a file and then compressed into a zip file in Linux OS. Then I moved this zip file to Windows and again copied it to another Linux server. This time I don't have the execute permission.

I know that we can directly copy the files and folders using scp command withing Linux but I have to let the user copy it from Windows to Linux also.

Please let me know how can I preserve the permissions while copying from Windows to Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since your executable file is *inside* a zip-archive it doesn't really matter what filesystem you're on or what operating system you're on. As long as the zip-archive is untouched.

However, as far as I know, zip-archives cannot keep track of file permissions. You can read more about it here:
[Maintain file and folder permissions inside archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735297/maintain-file-and-folder-permissions-inside-archives)

Answer (score 1):

It's up to whatever application is actually doing the copy.

But there are serious differences between the idea of file permissions on Linux/UNIX and Windows. UNIX file permissions have the idea of being "executable" which is not something that exists on Windows. Windows files are noted as runnable by their file extension not its permissions.

Furthermore, file permissions on UNIX have the concept of a group owner, and I don't think this exists on Windows so such a thing might not be possible in the strictest sense.

If you just want the writable/readable permissions as assigned to the owner to stick however, it will again depend on the application you are using to do the copy.

Answer (score 1):

More recently, you can also use the [Linux subsystem for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and zip the file using the linux shell command. I successfully did this recently when copying a executable for AWS from github to my Windows machine, and then up to Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses.

I found 2-solutions for my problem:

1. I am copying the complete zip file to the Linux server instead of copying a single file. This way it works fine.
2. Using cygwin helps me in copying the file onto a Linux server by preserving the execute permissions.