# Maintain file permission after gradle unzip

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a simple gradle task that unzips a zip file and copies it to a local directory. The problem is, after execution, all my files have their permissions changed.

This is my gradle task:

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
    def zipFile = file('src/dists/dist.zip')
    def outputDir = file("${buildDir}/unpacked/dist")

    from zipTree(zipFile)
    into outputDir
}
```

But after executing "unzip" task, all my files, which originally had

> rwxr-xr-x

permissions become

> rw-r--r--

Why is my task stripping execute permission from all my files? Is there a way to tell my gradle task to keep file permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that storing file permissions in zip file [is not trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735297/maintain-file-and-folder-permissions-inside-archives). It is not clear from your question if you have stored permissions in the zip file.

I don't know how to tell Gradle to *maintain* the permissions, but, this might be acceptable (?): the `fileMode` parameter on the `Copy` task ([doc here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:fileMode)) can be used to *assign* permissions.

For example:

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
    fileMode = 0755 
    def zipFile = file('src/dists/dist.zip')
    def outputDir = file("${buildDir}/unpacked/dist")

    from zipTree(zipFile)
    into outputDir
}
```

Results in permissions such as:

```
bash$ ls -lrt build/unpacked/dist/
total 0
-rwxr-xr-x  [snip] 9 Aug 22:42 run.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  [snip] 9 Aug 22:42 example1.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  [snip] 9 Aug 22:42 foobar.txt
```

Comment: After much digging, I did discover that the zip file most likely did not have the permissions I was expecting. Most likely due to the fact that it was zipped from a Windows OS. This solution will do, thanks!