# How to give CHMOD 0755 permission to all files in a jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to give read and write permission to all the files in the jar. Here is my build.gradle any suggestion experts ?

```
    task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.myapp.Main'
    }
    baseName = 'all-in-one-jar'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : 
      zipTree(it) } }
      with jar
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38862961/2970947

Comment: Thanks, but the link is about setting file permission after unzip, I want to set file permission in a jar.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, thanks above link helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding - fileMode = 0755

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.myapp.MyHandler'
}
fileMode = 0755

baseName = 'all-in-one-jar'
from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
} }
with jar
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to give read & write permissions, `0755` is the wrong bit mask for that, because that means read & execute. For read & write, use `0644`.