# Is it possible on Windows to mark a file in a zip file to Unix executable?

Tags: ruby, windows, unix, zip

Here's a bizarre question.  I have a continuous integration server (Windows 7) building Unity games.  One of those platforms I'm building for is Linux, which similar to the Windows building process, creates an executable file for that platform and a data folder.  Once I zip these files, then extract it on Linux though, the executable file is not marked for execution.  Is it possible in Windows to set this file's -- and only this file's -- permissions as an executable (e.g. `chmod +x filename`), and if so, how can I make that happen?

If scripting is involved, I don't mind which language it's in, but I do have a preference towards Ruby since that's what I'm using to automatically zip these files.  Here's what I have so far:

```
# Import modules
require 'zip'

# Define constants
PLATFORM_STRINGS = [' (Windows 32-bit)', \
                    ' (Windows 64-bit)', \
                    ' (Mac 32-bit)', \
                    ' (Mac 64-bit)', \
                    ' (Linux 32-bit)', \
                    ' (Linux 64-bit)', \
                    ' (Web)']

# Change directory
Dir.chdir(ARGV[0])

def get_application_name(directory)
    for platform in PLATFORM_STRINGS
        if directory.end_with?(platform)
            return directory.sub(platform, '')
        end
    end
end

# Find all directories in this folder
for directory in Dir['*']

    # Check if file is a directory
    if File.directory?(directory)

        # Retrieve the application name for this directory
        application_name = get_application_name(directory)
        zip_file_name = "#{directory}.zip"
        # Create a zip file
        Zip::File.open(zip_file_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|

            # Traverse recursively through all files
            Dir[File.join(directory, '**', '**')].each do |file|

                # Replace the top-level directory name with the application's name
                zipfile.add(file.sub(directory, application_name), file)
            end
        end

        # Indicate the zip file that was created
        puts "> Created: " + zip_file_name
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit messy; the ZIP format doesn't support this, but it does support "external attributes" for this kind of thing, assuming you're decompressing it with something that supports those.  See [the python version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zip), which has some well researched answers.

Answer (score 3):

Use my windows command line utility [zip_exec.zip](http://www.galaxy-forces.com/zip_exec.zip) to set the executable flag for unix and mac (tested on files created with Windows explorer and 7zip). The cpp [source](https://sourceforge.net/p/galaxyv2/code/HEAD/tree/other/zip_exec/) is also available.

Comment: You legend! Thank you. Works beautifully. I'll be distributing it with the OHRRPGCE engine for packaging.