# How to distribute an application for Mac OS so that it can be run by double clicking it?

Tags: python, macos, build

**Goal**

I've written a simple python application and I want to build it in a way such that I can email it to a non-technical person using a Mac OS machine such that they can just download the file and double click it to run.

**What I've tried so far**

I've built a single file executable using pyinstaller, but when I email it and download it, the file doesn't have permission to be executed. I know that this can be fixed with `chmod`, but the goal is for a non-technical person to be able to *just* double click to run.

I've also tried creating a "installation file" that's just a file with a `.command` file extension that is essentially this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd -- "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"
sudo chmod a+x MyApplication
exit 0
```

But this has the same problem as above - the file doesn't have permission to be run by default.

Is there something simple that I'm missing? I'm open to not necessarily having to email the app, but I do need a simple way to share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) allows scripts in different languages (including Python) to be bundled into OSX applications. Python is typically installed on newer versions of OSX anyway, so there might be no need to ship Python itself, and the app could be tiny in file size.

Generally, since OSX applications are really folders, it might be worthwile to pack the folder before emailing as

```
tar cjf YourApp.tbz YourApp
```

where `YourApp` is the folder containing the application. OSX recognizes the `tbz` extension and will unpack the app/folder when doubleclicked, say in Downloads or the Desktop, where the user can then doubleclick the application to run it.

```
tar cjf archive.tbz singlefile
```

will similarly also work for archiving a single file, where `tar` will preserve the executable and other flags.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only the execute bit, distribute the app in a format supporting that permission, e.g. ZIP and DMG. Yes, also ZIP supports the execute bit. You can set the execute bit in ZIP file even on Windows, the OS which doesn`t have these bits:
[Is it possible on Windows to mark a file in a zip file to Unix executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234447/is-it-possible-on-windows-to-mark-a-file-in-a-zip-file-to-unix-executable)

PS: The linked tool says unpacking ZIP file using Finder has a bug/feature it uses permission bits for all files according to the first file. Thus you have to set the execute bit to all of them. My experience differs, so mabye it was a bug in an older version of macOS.