# Create symlink inside a zipfile in memory using python

Tags: python, memory, symlink, python-zipfile

I am looking for a way to create a zipfile in memory and include a symlink inside the zipfile.
So far I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zip) and try the following code:

```
from zipfile import ZipInfo
from zipfile import ZipFile
from zipfile import ZIP_DEFLATED, ZIP_STORED
from cStringIO import StringIO
import codecs


buf = StringIO()
zipfile = ZipFile( buf,'w')

zipinfo = ZipInfo()
zipinfo.filename = u'bundle/'
zipinfo.compress_type = ZIP_STORED
zipinfo.external_attr = 040755 << 16L # permissions drwxr-xr-x
zipinfo.external_attr |= 0x10 # MS-DOS directory flag
zipfile.writestr(zipinfo, '')


path = u'bundle/test.txt'
zipinfo = ZipInfo(path)
zipinfo.compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED
zipinfo.external_attr = 0644 << 16L # permissions -r-wr--r--
zipfile.writestr(zipinfo, u'Test content')

dest = path

#create symbolic link (success)
zipinfo = ZipInfo()
zipinfo.filename = u'test_link.txt'
zipinfo.external_attr |= 0120000 << 16L # symlink file type
zipinfo.compress_type = ZIP_STORED
zipfile.writestr(zipinfo, dest)


#create symbolic link (failed)
zipinfo = ZipInfo()
zipinfo.filename = u'bundle1/test_link.txt'
zipinfo.external_attr |= 0120000 << 16L # symlink file type
zipinfo.compress_type = ZIP_STORED
zipfile.writestr(zipinfo, dest)

for info in zipfile.infolist():
    print u'filename %s' %info.filename
    print u'external_attr %s' %info.external_attr
    print u'header_offset %s' %info.header_offset
    print u'file_size %s' %info.file_size
    print u'crc %s' %info.CRC 
    print u'\n\n'


zipfile.close()
buf.reset()
with codecs.open('test.zip', 'w') as f:
    f.write(buf.getvalue())
buf.close()
```

The code above was able to create symlink successfully if the link is located directly under the root of unzip folder otherwise it is failed (after unzip if I try to open the symlink file bundle1/text1.txt, and it return an warning

> The operation can’t be completed because the original item for
>   “test_link.txt” can’t be found.

Could you please help me how to get symlink bundle1/test_link.txt works properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a symlink in `bundle1` that points to `bundle/test.txt`, the target would have to be located in `bundle1/bundle/test.txt`. Symlinks alre always relative to their own path (unless of course they start with a `/`)

So to make this work, you need to change the link destination to `../bundle/test.txt`.

Comment: Thank you ! I figured it out that I need to check the common prefix between the source and destination path and then use relative path to create symlink.

Comment: @mata : Is there something windows specific ? I am trying to create the symlink using the same technique but it is not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196350/how-to-create-symlink-in-zipfile-in-python/43196434#43196434