# How to create symlink in zipfile in python

Tags: python, symlink, python-zipfile

I have a zipfile which is stored in memory as `io.BytesIO` buffer. Within, the zipfile, I need to create a symlink to one of the directories.

Below is what I have tried so far (from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949548/create-symlink-inside-a-zipfile-in-memory-using-python) on SO) but it is not creating the link as I want at top level.

***Link to be created to*** : root/scale/lib/hypervisor/kvm/pika_3_5

***Link name*** : 'pika'

***Link location*** : at top level

***Existing Zipfile*** : data['egg_buffer']

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(data['egg_buffer'], 'a') as zip_buffer:
    dest = 'root/scale/lib/hypervisor/kvm/pika_3_5'
    info = zipfile.ZipInfo('pika')
    info.external_attr |= 0120000 << 16L # symlink file type
    info.compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_STORED
    zip_buffer.writestr(info, dest)
data['egg_buffer'].seek(os.SEEK_SET)
```

Actually this is creating a file at root level with name 'pika' but it is not a symlink and has content as text root/scale/lib/hypervisor/esx65/pika_3_5 instead.

Comment: Are you trying to extract this on windows? Unix symlinks don't work on windows, they will show up as file with the target as content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [archiving symlinks with python zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782941/archiving-symlinks-with-python-zipfile)