# AWS Lambda - Unable to import module

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I am attempting to upload a .zip file from S3 to run on a lambda function. When doing so, I get the following error:

```
START RequestId: 578fc1bb-9c82-11e7-b2c9-91da0a832381 Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'create_heatmap': No module named create_heatmap

END RequestId: 578fc1bb-9c82-11e7-b2c9-91da0a832381
REPORT RequestId: 578fc1bb-9c82-11e7-b2c9-91da0a832381  Duration: 0.31 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 18 MB
```

[image]

Above is the folder which I zipped up and uploaded to lambda. You can see there is a create_heatmap.py file in this top level directory.

The handler configuration I have laid out can be seen below:
[image]

And last, here is the lambda_handler function in create_heatmap.py.

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    hm = Heatmap(course_name=event.get('course_name',None),horizontal=event.get('horizontal',[]),num_topics=event.get('num_topics',10))
    hm.run()
```

I cannot figure out why this is not working at the moment. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would remove dependencies and do a quick test with a minimal Python source file that simply includes a lambda_handler(event, context) handler that prints "Hello World!".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the permissions on the files in the archive are at least 444 -- this tripped me up for awhile. If that doesn't work, check out the other answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340921/aws-lambda-import-module-error-in-python).