# AWS lambda "Unable to import module 'lambda_function" when I uncomment one of my imports

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda that takes images from an S3 and copies them to an Azure blob storage.

The start of my code looks like this:

```py
    import json
    import boto3
    # from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    import bson
    from urllib.parse import unquote
    from datetime import datetime
    import pytz
    import logging
```

This code runs fine. When I uncomment the azure storage line to get:

```py
    import json
    import boto3
    from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    import bson
    from urllib.parse import unquote
    from datetime import datetime
    import pytz
    import logging
```

I now get:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libffi-d78936b1.so.6.0.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Why does importing an azure library cause the entire lambda_handler to not work? I have successfully included all the other libraries in the AWS Lambda Layer, so it definitely exists. The entire Lambda runs fine when I comment out this line of code, so what's going on?

If there was an issue importing azure.storage.blob, wouldn't it say "Unable to import module azure.storage.blob"?

Comment: It does not exists, or may be in other directory. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340921/aws-lambda-import-module-error-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error due to the library not present in your Lambda Layer. Kindly try reconfiguring your Layer, or alternatively try creating a Deployment Package. Kindly refer to this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) to learn how to create a Deployment Package for a Lambda function.

As mentioned in the comment by [Atul Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7185816/atul-kumar), you could also have a look at this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340921/aws-lambda-import-module-error-in-python).

Comment: Yup, turned out to be a Layer issue. I was just confused as to why it said it couldn't find the entire lambd_handler rather than just the module that was missing!