# How to use git with lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, git, aws-lambda

I am trying to import the `git` library needed to clone the repo from gitlab. A lot of research suggested that the best way would be to add a `layer` to the lambda function. So, I created a lambda layer with the below commands:

```
mkdir lambda_layers
cd lambda_layers
mkdir python
cd python
pip install gitpython -t ./
cd .. && zip -r python_modules.zip .
```

When I added the zip file to the lambda function and tried running the function with nothing but just an import statement i.e `import git` and `print("hello world")` it gave me the below `error`:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': Failed to initialize: Bad git executable.
The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:
    - be included in your $PATH
    - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
    - explicitly set via git.refresh()

All git commands will error until this is rectified.

This initial warning can be silenced or aggravated in the future by setting the
$GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH environment variable. Use one of the following values:
    - quiet|q|silence|s|none|n|0: for no warning or exception
    - warn|w|warning|1: for a printed warning
    - error|e|raise|r|2: for a raised exception

Example:
    export GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet
```

So what am I missing here? My zip structure is the same as the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-upload) still the error.

Comment: This can be caused by a few things. Try checking some of the answers in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340921/aws-error-from-python-no-module-named-lambda-function

Comment: None of the solutions helped me. I am doing the zipping thing the right way. I tried multiple approaches but no luck.

Comment: @TrygviLaksafoss Well, I confirmed that this way of creating a layer is correct since I tried out other libraries but it's just that it doesn't work for `gitpython`  library