# zipfile in Python produces not quite normal ZIP files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

In my project set of files are created and packed to ZIP archive to be used at Android mobile phone. Android application is opening such ZIP files for reading initial data and then store results of its work to the same ZIPs. I have no access to source code of mentioned Android App and old script that generated zip files before (actually, I do not know how old ZIP files were created). But structure of ZIP archive is known and I have written new python script to make the same files.

I was faced with the following problem: ZIP files produced by my script cannot be opened by Android App (error message about incorrect file structure arrears), but if I unpack all the contents and pack it back to new ZIP file with the same name by **WinZIP**, **7-Zip** or "**Send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder**" (in Windows 7) file is normally processed on the phone (this leads me to the conclusion that the problem is not in the Android Application).

The code snippet for packing folder in ZIP was as follows

```
# make zip
try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(prefix + '.zip', 'w') as zipf:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(prefix):
            for file in files:
                zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
    # remove dir, that was packed
    shutil.rmtree(prefix)
    # Report about resulting
    print('File ' + prefix + '.zip was created')
except:
    print('Unexpected error occurred while creating file ' + prefix + '.zip')
```

After I noticed that files are not compressed I added compression option:

```
 zipfile.ZipFile(prefix + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

but this didn’t solve my problem and setting `True` value for `allowZip64` also didn’t change the situation.

By the way a ZIP file produced with `zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED` is about 5 kilobytes smaller than ZIP file produced by Windows and about 14 kilobytes smaller than 7-Zip’s result for the same archive content. At the same time all these ZIP files I can open for visual comparison by both 7-Zip and Windows Explorer.

So I have three related questions:

1) What may cause such strange behavior of my script with `zipfile`?

2) How else can I influence on `zipfile`?

3) How to check ZIP file created with `zipfile` to find possible structure problems or make sure there are no problems?

Of course, if I have to give up using `zipfile` I can use external archiver (e.g. 7-zip) for files packing, but I would like to find an elegant solution if it exists.

**UPDATE:**

In order to check content of ZIP file created with `zipfile` I made the following

```
# make zip
flist = []
try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(prefix + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(prefix):
            for file in files:
                zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
                # Store item in the list
                flist.append(os.path.join(root, file).replace("\\","/"))
    # remove dir, that was packed
    shutil.rmtree(prefix)
    # Report about resulting
    print('File ' + prefix + '.zip was created')
except:
    print('Unexpected error occurred while creating file ' + prefix + '.zip')
# Check of zip
with closing(zipfile.ZipFile(prefix + '.zip')) as zfile:
    for info in zfile.infolist():
        print(info.filename + \
              '  (extra = ' + str(info.extra) + \
              '; compress_type = ' + ('ZIP_DEFLATED' if info.compress_type == zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED else 'NOT ZIP_DEFLATED')  + \
              ')')
        # remove item from list
        if info.filename in flist:
            flist.remove(info.filename)
        else:
            print(info.filename + ' is unexpected item')
print('Number of items that were missed:')
print(len(flist))
```

And see the following results in the output:

```
File en_US_00001.zip was created
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_big.png  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_info.xml  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_small.png  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_source.pkl  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_source.tex  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_user.png  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_big.png  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_info.xml  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_small.png  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_source.pkl  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_source.tex  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_user.png  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_big.png  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_info.xml  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_small.png  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_source.pkl  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_source.tex  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_user.png  (extra = b''; compress_type = ZIP_DEFLATED)
Number of items that were missed:
0
```

Thus, all that was written, then was read, but the question remains - if all that is necessary has been written? E.g. in comments Harold said about relative paths... perhaps, it is the key to the answer

**UPDATE 2**

When I replaced `zipfile` by using external **7-Zip** code

```
# make zip
subprocess.call(["7z.exe","a",prefix + ".zip", prefix])
shutil.rmtree(prefix)
# Check of zip
with closing(zipfile.ZipFile(prefix + '.zip')) as zfile:
    for info in zfile.infolist():
        print(info.filename)
        print('  (extra = ' + str(info.extra) + '; compress_type = ' + str(info.compress_type) + ')')
print('Values for compress_type:')
print(str(zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) + ' = ZIP_DEFLATED')
print(str(zipfile.ZIP_STORED) + ' = ZIP_STORED')
```

produces the following result

```
Creating archive en_US_00001.zip

Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0001\en_US_00001_0001_big.png
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0001\en_US_00001_0001_info.xml
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0001\en_US_00001_0001_small.png
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0001\en_US_00001_0001_source.pkl
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0001\en_US_00001_0001_source.tex
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0001\en_US_00001_0001_user.png
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0002\en_US_00001_0002_big.png
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0002\en_US_00001_0002_info.xml
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0002\en_US_00001_0002_small.png
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0002\en_US_00001_0002_source.pkl
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0002\en_US_00001_0002_source.tex
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0002\en_US_00001_0002_user.png
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0003\en_US_00001_0003_big.png
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0003\en_US_00001_0003_info.xml
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0003\en_US_00001_0003_small.png
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0003\en_US_00001_0003_source.pkl
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0003\en_US_00001_0003_source.tex
Compressing  en_US_00001\en_US_00001_0003\en_US_00001_0003_user.png

Everything is Ok

en_US_00001/
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00Faf\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01Faf\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01%\xc9c\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 0)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\xbe(e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xbe(e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x016\xf0c\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 0)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_big.png
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00G\x17d\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01G\x17d\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01G\x17d\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_info.xml
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00X>d\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01X>d\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01X>d\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_small.png
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00z\x8cd\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01ied\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01ied\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_source.pkl
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x8b\xb3d\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\x8b\xb3d\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\x8b\xb3d\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_source.tex
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\xad\x01e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xad\x01e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xad\x01e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_user.png
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\xbe(e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xbe(e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xbe(e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x005:f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x015:f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xcfOe\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 0)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_big.png
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\xe0ve\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xcfOe\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xcfOe\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_info.xml
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\xf1\x9de\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xe0ve\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xe0ve\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_small.png
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x02\xc5e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\x02\xc5e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\x02\xc5e\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_source.pkl
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x13\xece\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\x13\xece\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\x13\xece\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_source.tex
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00$\x13f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01$\x13f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01$\x13f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_user.png
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x005:f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x015:f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x015:f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\xdf\xc0g\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xdf\xc0g\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01Faf\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 0)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_big.png
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00W\x88f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01W\x88f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01W\x88f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_info.xml
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00h\xaff\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01h\xaff\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01h\xaff\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_small.png
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x9b$g\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01y\xd6f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01y\xd6f\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_source.pkl
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\xacKg\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xacKg\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xacKg\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_source.tex
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\xce\x99g\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xce\x99g\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xce\x99g\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_user.png
    (extra = b'\n\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\xdf\xc0g\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xdf\xc0g\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01\xdf\xc0g\xd2Y\xf9\xd1\x01'; compress_type = 8)

Values for compress_type:
8 = ZIP_DEFLATED
0 = ZIP_STORED
```

As I understand the most important findings are:

- items with info for folders (e.g. `en_US_00001/`, `en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/`), that were not in the ZIP produced with my usage of `zipfile`
- folders have `compress_type == ZIP_STORED`, while for files `compress_type == ZIP_DEFLATED`
- `extra`s have different values (quite long strings were generated)

Comment: Did you try to pass `arcname` to `zipf.write` to store relative paths for files instead of full system paths? You can get relative path through `os.path.relpath`.

Comment: How about compare the good one and the bad one using `ZipFile.infolist()` to get information about the structure?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I have added some code to open and analyze created file by means of `zipfile`: `infolist` and `extractall` work normally - there are no problems when opening ZIP file

Comment: @VolAnd can you show us a comparison?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Update with my comparison approach was added

Comment: Can you also provide the `ZipInfo.extra` and `ZipInfo.compress_type` fields?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I have added more output

Comment: @Harold In the output provided in UPDATE I see path without external folders (I mean folders that are not in archive, and it is not full path) - Is your suggestion still topical?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that ZipFile is not storing those directories so the Android app has no directory to unpack to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the differences listed in UPDATE 2 of Question and examples from [other question about zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zip), I have tried the following code to add directories to ZIP file and check the result:

```
# make zip
try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(prefix + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
        info = zipfile.ZipInfo(prefix+'\\')
        zipf.writestr(info, '')
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(prefix):
            for d in dirs:
                info = zipfile.ZipInfo(os.path.join(root, d)+'\\')
                zipf.writestr(info, '')
            for file in files:
                zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
    # remove dir, that was packed
    shutil.rmtree(prefix)
    # Report about resulting
    print('File ' + prefix + '.zip was created')
except:
    print('Unexpected error occurred while creating file ' + prefix + '.zip')
# Check zip content
with closing(zipfile.ZipFile(prefix + '.zip')) as zfile:
    for info in zfile.infolist():
        print(info.filename)
        print('  (extra = ' + str(info.extra) + '; compress_type = ' + str(info.compress_type) + ')')
print('Values for compress_type:')
print(str(zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) + ' = ZIP_DEFLATED')
print(str(zipfile.ZIP_STORED) + ' = ZIP_STORED')
```

Output is

```
File en_US_00001.zip was created
en_US_00001/
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 0)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 0)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 0)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 0)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_big.png
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_info.xml
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_small.png
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_source.pkl
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_source.tex
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0001/en_US_00001_0001_user.png
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_big.png
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_info.xml
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_small.png
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_source.pkl
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_source.tex
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0002/en_US_00001_0002_user.png
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_big.png
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_info.xml
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_small.png
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_source.pkl
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_source.tex
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
en_US_00001/en_US_00001_0003/en_US_00001_0003_user.png
    (extra = b''; compress_type = 8)
Values for compress_type:
8 = ZIP_DEFLATED
0 = ZIP_STORED
```

Adding slash to directory names (`+'\\'` or `+'/'`) appeared mandatory.

And the most important thing - now ZIP file is properly accepted by Android Application.

Comment: So I guessed right? Congratulations on fixing your problem.