# Zip with dependencies and permissions in Python

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to automate a process to zip a python file and all of its dependencies with 755 permissions. (The reason for this is to upload them for an AWS Lambda which requires 755 permissions on the file).

If I just wanted to zip with dependencies I would just run

`zip -r9 ${OLDPWD}/function.zip .`

And, from [How do I set permissions (attributes) on a file in a ZIP file using Python's zipfile module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zip) I was able to write a python script to zip with permissions using

```
def main(lambda_filename):
    zipname = lambda_filename + ".zip"
    filename = lambda_filename + ".py"

    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    f = open(filename, 'r')
    bytes = f.read()
    f.close()

    info = zipfile.ZipInfo(filename)
    info.external_attr = 0o755 << 16

    zip.writestr(info, bytes, zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    zip.close()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    main(filename)
```

But, how would I combine these two so that I can zip all my dependencies and then add my file with the 755 permissions? Is there some way I can run my `zip -r9` and then add my file later without overwriting?

Thanks!

Comment: Based on your last sentence I presume you're asking for `mode='a'` when instantiating [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) which would then also be your answer.