# Can I set the permissions of the contents of a dynamically generated zip file in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, permissions, zip

In my app engine script (using the Python API), I'm using [this code](http://www.tareandshare.com/2008/09/28/Zip-Google-App-Engine-GAE/) to dynamically generate zip files and serve them back to the user. When I download and extract the generated zip file and I'm running OS X, the permissions of each file extracted from the archive is 0, forcing me to chmod them. I'd rather not have my users have to do the same. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279945/set-permissions-on-a-compressed-file-in-python may be helpful, although the solution may need to be adapted a bit to work within a StringIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, see the docs for the Python [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module. Specifically, the signature of the `writestr` method, which is:

> ZipFile.writestr(zinfo_or_arcname,
>   bytes[, compress_type])

The first argument can be the filename, or a [ZipInfo](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects) object, which allows you to specify information about the file to be stored. I believe the relevant field to set to change the permissions of the file is the external_attr, but some experimentation reading existing zip files may be required to determine this.