# Setting correct permissions on generated zip-file in Django

Tags: python, django, permissions, zip

I'm using Django and Python2.6 to generate a zip file of custom-rendered Django templates for each user to download a custom-made `zip` file. At the moment, the code in `views.py` looks like this:

```
def download(request):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/x-zip-compressed')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=download.zip'

    myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(response, 'w')

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    zipInfo = zipfile.ZipInfo('thefile.txt', (now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second))
    myzip.writestr(zipInfo, render_to_string('template.txt', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request)))
    myzip.close()

    return response
```

Mostly, this works fine: the zip file (containing a single `txt` file in this example) is downloaded correctly, and I can extract the contents. The only problem is, however, that the permissions on the generated file are neither `read` nor `write` for my default user, and neither will it be for my website users.

How do I change the permissions of the auto-generated file before download?

***Update*:**

I've tried using `os.chmod` and `os.fchmod`, as suggested by Mike, but this either requires a path name (which I don't have) or gives an error (for `fchmod`):

`ZipFile instance has no attribute '__trunc__'`

One option, I guess, would be to save the zip file first, setting the permissions, and then allowing download, but that seems like overkill - there must be a better way to overcome this simple problem. Anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

***Update2*:**

It seems this issue is limited to Unix systems, as it works fine in Windows and (apparently) OS X. There's a similar thread I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279945/445210). As far as I can tell, it must be related to the `writestr` method. How do I set the permissions on a file added to a zip file with `writestr`?

Comment: Which file has the wrong permissions: the downloaded ZIP file or the text file within the zip file?

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: The text file within the zip file.

Comment: @vartec: Yes, and that seems to the root of my problem. The response is downloaded as a zip file, but the contents permissions are wrong, and I can't set the permissions, because there is no file to set (yet).

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434641/how-do-i-set-permissions-attributes-on-a-file-in-a-zip-file-using-pythons-zipf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279945/set-permissions-on-a-compressed-file-in-python

Comment: @vartec: In the end, yes. But for a long time I thought the problem had something to do with me returning the zip file as a response in Django - so perhaps some day someone else using Django might make the same wrong assumption, and then this will be helpful.

Comment: @Herman: I've just checked using regular files, this seems to have actually nothing to do with if it's Django response or regular file.

Comment: @vartec: I know, I'm just motivating why I think this question should not be deleted.

Comment: @Herman: it won't, it has bounty and answers.

Comment: @vartec: Oh ok, did not know what the prerequisites are.

Comment: @Herman: also questions which are duplicate, get closed not deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an issue with whatever you are using to extract the zip. The permissions seem fine to me:

```
zk@fool:~/Downloads% ls -l | grep thefile
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 zk  staff           9 May  3 06:37 thefile.txt*
```

Works fine for me with Archive Utility on osx and window's built-in zip explorer and 7-zip. Inspecting the generated zip shows files have no attributes at all. So I suspect whatever you are using to unzip the file is just setting permissions incorrectly.

You could try setting ZipInfo.external_attr:

```
zipInfo.external_attr = 0777 << 16L # set permissions on file
```

seems to fix the permissions on a linux system:

```
zk@arch:~% ls -l | grep thefile
-rwxrwxrwx  1 zk     9 May  3 07:06 thefile.txt*
```

Comment: Yes, according to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279945/445210) it seems to me that the issue is limited to Unix systems.

Comment: maybe try settings ZipInfo.external_attr or internal_attr?

Comment: @zeekay: Ah yes, I just checked that myself after seeing the other thread, and that solved the problem.

Comment: @zeekay: But it has to be `zipInfo.external_attr = 0777 << 16L`

Comment: Yeah that should really be documented: http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.external_attr

Answer (score 0):

In unix every process have default file permissions mask.. read on:
umask
try setting it for django process.